# Finding limits using a graph

Tags: calculus, limits

[image: mim]

I was given this graph and asked to find $\lim_{x\to2}\frac{x}{f(x)+1}$. I used direct substitution and got $\frac20$. This, however, is not correct. Why not? What is the correct answer - and where am I going wrong?

**Is it possible to break down the steps to do when seeing this problem?**

Comment: As to why your answer is not correct, try putting it into a calculator and see what the answer is.

Comment: Division by $0$ is not admissible, so the answer is the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: The answer is infinity. But, I don't know why or how to get there.

Comment: @David - what should I put into the calculator to see why my answer is incorrect?

Comment: Put in the answer you have given: two divided by zero.

Comment: Yes, but that answer would just mean that my limit does not exist.

Comment: The limit diverges to $\infty$, and hence doesn't exist. How? Evaluate the right and left hand limits separately.

Comment: The answer key gives the answer as infinity. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @burt, sorry, made a typo

Comment: @ShubhamJohri can you remind me what it means when the limit diverges to infinity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Is $\frac{x}{f(x)+1}$ continuous at $x = 2$?  The numerator is continuous at $x = 2$, taking the value $2$.  The denominator is continuous at $x = 2$, taking the value $0$.  The quotient $\frac{x}{f(x)+1}$ is discontinuous because division by $0$ is undefined.  Since the function is discontinuous at $x = 2$, direct substitution cannot give you the answer.

Step 2: Time to inspect the graph we are given.  What are the values of the numerator *near* $x = 2$?  They are values near $2$.  What are the values of $f(x)+1$?  They are nonnegative values near zero (and are only zero at $x = 2$).  This means that $\frac{x}{f(x)+1}$ is a ratio of positive values (near but not at $x = 2$) and schematically are $\frac{\text{near }2}{\text{small positive number or $0$}}$.  In fact, as $x$ approaches $2$, the numerator approaches $2$ and the denominator gets as small as you like.  The ratio of $2$ to a number as small as you like can be made as large as you like by picking an even smaller denominator.  Thus, from both sides, the limit as $x \rightarrow 2$ increases without upper bound (which is the definition of diverging to $+\infty$).

Step 3: Summarize.  This limit does not exist.  We can also observe that this limit diverges to $\infty$ (since this is a particularly common variety of "not existing" that comes up often enough to justify calling it out explicitly).  The typical abuse of notation is to write
$$  \lim_{x \rightarrow 2} \frac{x}{f(x)+1} = \infty  \text{.}  $$
(Everyone using and reading that notation is expected to understand that this is not an equality of quantities, but is an abbreviation of "the limit does not exist and in fact diverges to $+\infty$.")